How can I use searchSuggestion to perform an API search in my SwiftUI app?
My goal is to have a search view in my app where users can search by entering a text and submitting it. While a user is typing I want to display search suggestions.
The on submit of the search text works. Suggestions are displayed as well while a user is typing, however, I don't know how to perform a search when a suggestion is tapped. How can I achieve this?
Currently this is the search functionality (skeleton) of my search view.
struct SearchView: View {
    @Bindable var viewData = SearchViewData()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(viewData.searchResults) { result in
                    Text(result.value)
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $viewData.searchText)
        .onSubmit(of: .search, runSearch)
        .searchSuggestions {
            ForEach(viewData.suggestedSearches) { suggestion in
                Text("\(suggestion.term)").searchCompletion(suggestion)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: viewData.searchText) {
            fetchSearchSuggestions()
        }
    }

    func runSearch() {
        await viewData.runSearch() // The suggestedSearches gets cleared so they arent displayed anymore
    }

    func fetchSearchSuggestions() {
        if !viewData.searchText.empty {
            Task {
                await viewData.fetchSearchSuggestions()
            }
        }
    }
}


unrelated but you should use task to run your search, e.g. .task(id: submittedSearch) {     results = await searchController.search(submittedSearch) } where results is a state and searchconController is an EnvironmentKey struct (so you can swap it out with a mock for previews).

Interesting. I'm still new to SwiftUI development, do you have any resources that explain the advantages of running the search using task and on using EnvironmentKey for my searchController? I haven't seen that task notation before and didn't know the EnvironmentKey annotation existed so I'd like to learn more.
